# Vscode flutter debugging for android stuck on a blank screen

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

When i am trying to debug android it stuck on a blank screen (black) in real device, but it's working on emulator. [image: This is the result]

Device: Vivo T2X 5g
Android version: 13

### Debugging

I/flutter (19963): The Dart VM service is listening on ************************************
D/FlutterGeolocator(19963): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(19963): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(19963): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator(19963): Initializing Geolocator services
D/FlutterGeolocator(19963): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1